# Python multiprocessing hive hang in Linux

Tags: python, hive, multiprocessing

The code below worked in Windows but in Linux is hanging:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
from multiprocessing import Pool
conn = connect(host='172.16.12.12', port=10000, user='hive', password='hive', database='test',auth_mechanism='PLAIN')

cur = conn.cursor()
def test_hive(a):
    cur.execute('select {}'.format(a))
    tab_cc = cur.fetchall()
    tab_cc =tab_cc[0][0]
    print(a,tab_cc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    alist=[1,2,3]
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        pool.apply_async(test_hive,str(i))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

When I change `alist=[1,2,3]` to `alist=[1]` it works in Linux.

Comment: Python version?

Comment: @MatrixTai Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible causes for this behavior:

1. an exception raised in `test_hive` in the context of a forked subprocess
2. a deadlock caused by the fact that `fork` does not copy threads from the parent and/or the fact that mutexes are copied in the state they have when the fork call is executed

To check for exceptions, add `return tab_cc` to the end of your `test_hive` function and gather the results returned by the pool:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    alist = [1,2,3]
    results = []
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        results.append(pool.apply_async(test_hive, str(i)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for result in results:
        try:
            print(result.get())
        except Exception as e:
            print("{}: {}".format(type(e).__name__, e))
```

As for the threads, I did a quick search through the `impala` repo and it seems like they somehow play a role around the usage of `thrift`. I'm not sure if Python's threading module can actually see them, when originating from that library. You might try with `print(multiprocessing.current_process(), threading.enumerate())`, both at the module level (e.g. after `cur = conn.cursor()`) and at the beginning of the `test_hive` function and see if the `_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)` shows a longer list of active threads than all of the `ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-<worker#>, started daemon)`.

As for a potential solution: I somewhat suspect the fact that you create `conn` and `cur` at the module level to be the culprit; all childs use a copy of those two.
Try and move these two lines to the beginning of `test_hive`, so that each process creates a connection and a cursor if its own:

```
conn = connect(host='172.16.12.12', port=10000, user='hive', password='hive', database='test',auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
import time,datetime,sys,re
import psycopg2 as pg
today = datetime.date.today()
from multiprocessing import Pool

def test_hive(a):
    conn = connect(host='172.16.12.12', port=10000, user='hive', password='hive', database='test',auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    #print(a)
    cur.execute('select {}'.format(a))
    tab_cc = cur.fetchall()
    tab_cc =tab_cc[0][0]
    return tab_cc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    alist = [1,2,4,4,4,4,5,3]
    results = []
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        results.append(pool.apply_async(test_hive, str(i)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for result in results:
        try:
            print(result.get())
        except Exception as e:
            print("{}: {}".format(type(e).__name__, e))
```

I move these two lines to test_hive  is worked.

```
conn = connect(host='172.16.12.12', port=10000, user='hive', password='hive', database='test',auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
cur = conn.cursor()
```